# emails sent from production server end up in spam

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail, production-environment, spam, email-spam

I use **sendmail** to send emails from my application. I always send the emails from SOME_NAME@MY_DOMAIN.com but they always endup in spam folder.

I know that I should do some stuff on the *DNS side* to make my emails be marked as non-spam, but I don't know what they are. 
I am a newbie and this is my first time setting up a production server, a domain and everything else myself. I appreciate if someone helps me.

Comment: I voted this up, but also voted to have it closed and moved to serverfault. You should get better answers over there.

Comment: The best article I have read on that topic was Jeff’s: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll read the article right now.

Comment: Look at raw email headers of email flagged as spam.  There are usually descriptions of why it was flagged as spam.

Comment: Sebastien, that's an awesome tutorial! I'm out of the dark, and things are making more sense! Post is as an answer please!

Comment: I created SPF records using the microsoft wizard and dig MX works properly as well. But my emails still end up in spam. The only suspicious element in the header is: X-Authentication-Warning: ip-MY_IP.ec2.internal: ec2-user set sender to robot@scholarnetwork.org using -f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sort of environment are you deploying to?

This frequently happens to applications deployed to cloud services, like Amazon or RackSpace. Their entire IP blocks are registered as spam at services like [Spamhaus](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso), which is a sensible precaution or else we'd be getting even more spam than usual. You should enter your server's IP address in that field to see if you're listed as a spammer.

If you are, you can request to Spamhaus that the block be lifted. Getting in touch with Amazon's support stuff also helps. Finally, you can get around the issue entirely by using a sendmail service of some sort -- Amazon SES is pretty good, and there's even a [Gem out there](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses) that provides integration to Rails apps.

Comment: yes. I'm deploying to amazon ec2. I see, I'll look at Amazon SES.

Comment: Glad I helped! Accept my answer so that future people on Stack Overflow will be likely to help you too. ;)